# How to align object to z-axis when distributed on a plane using geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, axis

I have many objects on a plane like this:
[image: description of plane]
Each object on the mesh points the way the plane is facing, however how would I make them align to the z-axis so they are all straight up like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just plug "nothing" in rotation like this:

[image]

then it will take the rotation of the instance object itself.

[image]